# PHP: add tags to text that comes from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text in a MySql database. I suppose I should not put tags in the database. If so, how do I add p tags when I echo that text in a html page?

For instance I have that in the database (three paragraphs):

paragraph 1

paragraph 2

paragraph 3

When I use php in the page to echo the text:

```
$text = $row['first'];
echo $text;//this gives: paragraph 1paragraph 2paragraph 3
```

This is what I try to get:

```
<p>paragraph 1</p> 

<p>paragraph 2</p>

<p>paragraph 3</p>
```

Comment: `echo nl2br($text);` http://php.net/nl2br

Comment: Replace new lines with `</p><p>`

Comment: [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) could replace your newlines in database with paragraph-tags. If you don't directly care about the paragraph-tags, you could do `nl2br($string);` as already suggested.

Comment: @Charlotte: nl2br gives br not p tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know you have `\n` line break, then :

```
    // the full text
$text = "paragraph 1\n\nparagraph 2\n\nparagraph 3";

    // remove \n and space at start/end
$text = trim( $text ); 

    // the paragraph break 
$paragraphBreak = array("\r\n\r\n", "\n\r\n\r", "\n\n", "\r\r");

    // add the <p> tag
$text = '<p>'.str_replace( $paragraphBreak, '</p><p>', $text ).'</p>';

    // display with <br> tag
echo nl2br( $text );
```

this'll add the `<br>` tag, and make a new `<p>` if you jump one line

Comment: I've add the `trim()` to remove blank line at the end/start

Comment: @Nrc work perfectly for me.. strange; what do you get as html source output with this code ?

Comment: In a real case, I do not know what I have in $paragraphBreak. What I give is just an example. The question is how to output text with p tags

Comment: Just change the $text for you text, don't touch the $paragraphBreak. The problem is : you should have a blank line between two paragraph, if not then it's assumed as the same one. This code should work, but if you have tab `\t` or space on the blank line, then it'll not make a new `<p>`. what do you get if you var_dump this : `str_replace( ["\n","\r","\t"], ["#n","#r","#t"], $text )` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
echo '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
```

Comment: this makes just one paragraph, not 3 paragraphs like in the example

Comment: Array ( [0] => paragref 1 paragref 2 [1] => paragref 3 )

Comment: See for any factor to distinguish between the paragraphs...If the paragraphs were separated with two new line '\n\n' then the explode method would have worked.But now it would give like <p>paragraph 1 paragraph 2</p> and <p>paragraph 3 </p>